# Prevent using ThreadPoolExecutor while it is being restarted

Tags: java, android, multithreading, executorservice

In an Android application I have a ThreadPoolExecutor executing background threads. Most of this requests are being called from the UI thread, like for example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    executor.execute(runnable);
}
```

The problem arises when the user logs out from my application, in the logout process I shutdown this executor and then create it again to ensure that there aren't tasks running when the new user logs in.

```
void logout(){
    executor.shutdownNow();
    ExecutorServiceUtils.waitForTermination(executor);
    executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
}
```

And in some circunstances, I'm having racing conditions where the UI tries to executor.execute() while the executor is being "restarted". To prevent this I want to prevent the UI to execute tasks while the executor is restarting. Of course I can lock the UI thread with any Java's barrier such as locks, synchronized, semaphores, but I don't consider it a good approach (the UI will be locked).

Neither I can't refactor all the calls to the executor, I need to make the executor thread safe.

Since I assume this is a common situation, is there any logic way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: You're waiting for the new one, not the old one. You need another variable.

Comment: sorry, my mistake while copying the code, actually the executor is in a wrapper, so I simplified the code here. Edited now

Comment: Should you perhaps create the new Executor first, and assign it, and then shutdown the old one? Not sure why any of this is considered necessary. I don't understand for example why you don't just shutdown the old executor and not start the new one until a login happens.

Comment: There are tasks that are being executing even before login (check SMS in background, for example). But your solution to have a new one while the old one is being closed sounds much simpler than my idea. I'm going to try it.

Comment: Tested and working, simple and clean solution, if you write it as an answer I will mark it as correct